# Convert Google Sheets to CSV with URL using Python

Tags: python, csv, url, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure how to make this program (found online) take a URL or Google Sheets ID instead of a name to find the document and convert to CSV. Currently it takes a file name and functions properly. This is my first time using APIs and I haven't worked with python in a while so any help is appreciated!

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os


from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools



SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

FILENAME = 'No Name'
SRC_MIMETYPE = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
DST_MIMETYPE = 'text/csv'

files = DRIVE.files().list(
    q='name="%s" and mimeType="%s"' % (FILENAME, SRC_MIMETYPE),
    orderBy='modifiedTime desc,name').execute().get('files', [])

if files:
    fn = '%s.csv' % os.path.splitext(files[0]['name'].replace(' ', '_'))[0]
    print('Exporting "%s" as "%s"... ' % (files[0]['name'], fn), end='')
    data = DRIVE.files().export(fileId=files[0]['id'], mimeType=DST_MIMETYPE).execute()
    if data:
        with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
        print('DONE')
    else:
        print('ERROR (could not download file)')
else:
    print('!!! ERROR: File not found')
```

edit: to add clarity

Comment: In your question, you say `I am trying to figure how to make this program (found online) take a URL or Google Sheets ID instead of a name to find the document.`. But in your title, you say `Convert Google Sheets to CSV with URL using Python`. By this, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Currently the program converts a google sheet to a CSV, but it requires the name of the document. I want to be able to use the URL/Google Sheet ID instead of a name to locate the document. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you it seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to export a Google Spreadsheet as a CSV file using a Spreadsheet ID instead of Spreadsheet name.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to get values from Google Drive using Drive API.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, in order to retrieve the Spreadsheet ID, the method of "Files: list" is used using the Spreadsheet name, and the Spreadsheet is exported as a CSV using the method of "Files: export.
- In order to achieve your goal, you can directly use the Spreadsheet ID for the method of "Files: export.
- And, in your script, the file name is retrieved from the Spreadsheet name. In this case, the method of "Files: get" is used for retrieving the Spreadsheet name from the Spreadsheet ID.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. Please modify your script below `DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

spreadsheetId = '###' # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
DST_MIMETYPE = 'text/csv'

# Retrieve Spreadsheet name from Spreadsheet ID.
res1 = DRIVE.files().get(fileId=spreadsheetId).execute()

# Export Spreadsheet as CSV.
fn = '%s.csv' % os.path.splitext(res1['name'].replace(' ', '_'))[0]
print('Exporting "%s" as "%s"... ' % (res1['name'], fn), end='')
data = DRIVE.files().export(
    fileId=spreadsheetId, mimeType=DST_MIMETYPE).execute()
if data:
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
    print('DONE')
else:
    print('ERROR (could not download file)')
```

#### References:

- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)